# Prove that the sum of values in the complex plane coincides with the diagonal of parallelogram

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the figure

[image: complex plane]

Which represents the vectors $z$ and $w$ in the complex plane (the drawing is an approximation).

I want to prove that $z+w$ is just the diagonal of the parallelogram formed by $z$ and $w$.

If we define the diagonal of such a parallelogram by

$d=\sqrt{w^2+z^2-wz \cos \Theta}$ and in polar coordinates we can represent the sum of two complex numbers by

$$z+w=|z|(\cos \Theta_{z} +i \sin\Theta_{z})+|w|(\cos \Theta_{w} +i \sin\Theta_{w})=(|z|\cos \Theta_{z}+|w|\cos \Theta_{w})+i(|z| \sin \Theta_{z}+|w| \sin \Theta_{w})$$

How can I establish such equality, between the diagonal and the sum, is the only idea I can think of. Any suggestions?

Comment: You’re not using anything about $\mathbb{C}$ besides that it’s a two-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. So just do it over $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: You're using the "diagonal" to mean both the line segment and the length of that line segment. For example, is the diagonal defined as the line segment of length $d$ from $(0,0)$ to $(a+c,b+d)$? If so, you might as well just re-compute $d$ using the Pythagorean theorem.